# Dropdown list size issues when filtering content

Tags: c#, combobox, dropdown

I have an issues with the size of my drop down list. Default height is set to 250 and original list has a nice scroll bar as per print screen below when I open the list manually.

[image]

The issue begins when I start typing to find a matching records. As soon as I start typing(without opening the list), the size of the drop down list changes as per below:
[image]

This is fine. However, this leads to a real problem. If a filtered item was selected, it will appear in the combobox as expected. However, when I open the drop down list  with the content of the previous selection still in combobox, the size of the list is small and contains only the matched records.

[image]

While the small list is still open with just 3 records, I delete the content, the size of my drop down remains the same but the list contains all records and there is a tiny scroll bar on the RHS rather then resetting itself to the original size. After removing the content i need to display the full list as per 1st print screen.

[image]

I have the following code in place where I have tried to reset the Drop down list size to its original 250 but no luck: PLEASE HELP!!!

```
private void SelectJobComboBox_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectJobComboBox.Text))
    {
        this.filteredItems.Clear();
        SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = arrProjectList;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        SelectJobComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        RunBTN.Enabled = false;             

    }
    else
    {

        string filter_param = SelectJobComboBox.Text;
       filteredItems = arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.ToLower().Contains(filter_param.ToLower()));


        if (filteredItems.Count == 0)
        {
            FilterMatchFound = false;
            filteredItems.Insert(0, "No matches found");
            // SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = filteredItems;
            SelectJobComboBox.DropDownHeight = 250;
            SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = arrProjectList;
             SelectJobComboBox.IntegralHeight = true;
            RunBTN.Enabled = false;
            JobNumberTextBox.Text = "";
            JobDescriptiontextBox.Text = "";

        }
        else
        {
            SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = filteredItems; //list all matching items. 
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
        {
            SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = arrProjectList;  //assign original list of directories
        }
        SelectJobComboBox.IntegralHeight = false;                
        SelectJobComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        SelectJobComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

        SelectJobComboBox.Text = filter_param;

        SelectJobComboBox.SelectionStart = filter_param.Length;
        SelectJobComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }  
}

private void SelectJobComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Clear variables and lists every time an item is selected from the list
    this.sProjectNameFull = "";

    if (this.FilterMatchFound == true)
    {

        //Split directory name into qualifiers 
        string[] sDirectoryNameSplit = SelectJobComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
        this.sProjectNameFull = SelectJobComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //populate project number text box with 1st part of directory name
        JobNumberTextBox.Text = sDirectoryNameSplit[0];
        this.sProjectNumber = sDirectoryNameSplit[0];

        //concatenate parts of directory name into project name - start after 3rd qualifier
        sbProjectName.Clear();
        for (int j = 3; j < sDirectoryNameSplit.Length; j++)
        {
            sbProjectName.Append(sDirectoryNameSplit[j]).Append(' ');
        }

        //populate project name text box with project name built in the loop
        JobDescriptiontextBox.Text = sbProjectName.ToString();

    }
    else
    {

    }

    //enable run button
    RunBTN.Enabled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `IntegralHeight` to `false` in the `SelectJobComboBox_TextUpdate` event.

Set it to true and your original height will be visible

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
{
    SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = arrProjectList;  //assign original list of directories
}
SelectJobComboBox.IntegralHeight = true;
SelectJobComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
```

**EDIT: **

The problem is explained in the **remarks** in the [ComboBox.DropDownHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownheight(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Setting the DropDownHeight property resets the IntegralHeight property to false.

So your first if-condition should look like this:

```
private void comboBox2_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectJobComboBox.Text))
    {
        this.filteredItems.Clear();                
        SelectJobComboBox.DataSource = arrProjectList;

        SelectJobComboBox.DropDownHeight = 100; // select here how many items you want to be displayed
        SelectJobComboBox.DroppedDown = true;  // and force the combobox to open up

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        SelectJobComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

this will ensure that the dropdown occurs as far as you wish it to be.
So you need to choose, either set `IntegralHeight` to true and let the combobox decide or set `DropDownHeight` and decide yourself.

Comment: I copied your `SelectJobComboBox_TextUpdate` code and could reproduce the error, then I changed the value, and the problem disappeared. Do you have any other events where you change any of the combobox properties?

Comment: I had SelectJobComboBox_TextChanged, SelectJobComboBox_Click & SelectJobComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged but I did not have any code in there. I have removed it but still getting the same issue.

Comment: It opens a full list but I want to go back to the original size with a scroll bar where this one seems to fit all items into the drop down which will be problemtic when number of items in the list increases.

Comment: @TomPisz after more than 30 entries it will automatically put a scrollbar in the combobox. Try a list with 45 items

Comment: Great thanks. Its really strange!! i just cant understand why it does not return to the default size. Thanks again.